# Add onClick event to action button in notification android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I have gone through a couple of stackoverflow answers and also a couple of tutorials to add actions to the action buttons in notifications in android. I am using the NotificationCompat to create a notification and the notification has two action buttons. Since, the third argument in the action button is a pending intent, I was curious whether there is a way to attach a click event method directly to the action button. Please find the code for the BroadcastReceiver and the place where I create the notification.

AlarmManager:

```
 notifyMed.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Notify clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*1000;

                Intent alertIntent = new Intent(mContext, AlertReceiver.class);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime ,
                        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext , 1 , alertIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Here is the code for BroadCastReceiver:

BroadCastReceiver:

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

int notificationId = 6324;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    createNotification(context, "Medication Notification" , "It is time to take your medication", "Message From PHMS");
}

public void createNotification(Context context, String msgTitle, String msgContentText, String msgTicker){

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MedicationNotification.class) , 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cardiogram)
            .setContentTitle(msgTitle)
            .setTicker(msgTicker)
            .setContentText(msgContentText);

    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    mBuilder.setSound(uri);

    long[] vibrate = {500,1000};
    mBuilder.setVibrate(vibrate);


    mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_snooze_black_24dp,"Snooze", pendingIntent);
    mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_check_circle_black_24dp,"Take Medication", pendingIntent);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);

    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Here is the code for androidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".activities.AlertReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".activities.MedicationNotification"></activity>
</application>
```

I just want to handle a click event on the notification action buttons. The notification is generated correctly. Kindly help!

Comment: Have the pendingIntent fire a different BroadcastReciever for each action and put the code in the reciever

Comment: @nickfriskel - Could you please elaborate? Just like sample codee?